# Calculate gradient over different spacing than prescribed latitude/longitude grid in python

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf4

I want to use the numpy.gradient function to calculate gradient components of .nc4 variables like soil moisture/temperature. The grid spacing/resolution of my data is extremely small (around ~9km) and I was interested in calculating the gradient across a larger delta (like 100km). Is this possible to do using the gradient function alone or do I have to regrid my data to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.gradient` is doing a [2-point centered difference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) approximation for the first derivative. If your data are 9km and you want a 100km estimate, you need to decide how you'd want that calculated. Fit a line to the data and take the slope? Fit some higher order curve? Essentially `gradient` is using the fewest points it can, but if you want it across 100km you have many more points and need to decide how best to use/reduce them.